# Moling DataContext with MS Moles?

Tags: c#, mocking, pex-and-moles, moles

How can I mole the DataContext that I'm using in a class to write messages to a table. I'd like to assert that the table LINQ is writing to has the expected count of messages. Here's what i have so far.

```
var context = new MJustTestingDataContext();
MyMessagewriter writer = new MyMessageWriter(context);

var messageList = new List<MIncmoingMessage>();
MTable<MIncomingMessage> messageTable = new MTable<MIncomingMessage>();
messageTable.Bind(messagesLinqList.AsQueryable());
```

If I use this code with xUnit in my class under test I'll get this exception

```
Microsoft.Moles.Framework.Moles.MoleNotImplementedException: DataContext.Dispose() was not moled.
```

What am I missing here and how to implement DataContext.Dispose() on the mole? I'm using moles standalone without Pex.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new Mole the default behavior for its methods and properties is to throw a `MoleNotImplementedException` whenever they are called.

<strike>To implement the mole you can do `context.Dispose = () => {};` which means that nothing happens when the `Dispose` method gets called on the moled instance.</strike>
I reread the question and you probably are having a problem since `Dispose` is defined in a base class. To mole base method you need to do the following:

```
var context = new MJustTestingDataContext();
var baseContext = new MDataContext(context);

baseContext.Dispose = () => {};
```

You'll need to implement every property/method that gets called by the code under test or you can set the default behavior for the mole instance globally using the method `BehaveAsDefaultValue`. This way every method in the mole will do nothing and return the default value for it's return type if one exists instead of throwing a `MoleNotImplementedException`. However if you require this behavior it's better to use a stub than a mole.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding what your test is doing. I had to do something similar yesterday, so I'll share my experience. First, it's important to understand that you don't need to use all the MoleTypes to test your code -- you just need to use Moles to redirect certain parts of your code to lambda expressions. Given a method that does this:

1. get a list of users to modify from the database
2. modify every user in the set
3. send the new set back to the database

I'd like to redirect 1 and 3 to not use the database. For instance, I can redirect the call to `SubmitChanges` (3) via this code:

```
bool hitSubmitChanges = false;
int changeCount = 0;
IList<object> updates = null;

// more code here... 

   // redirect DataContext.SubmitChanges() to a lambda to catch updates 
   MDataContext.AllInstances.SubmitChanges = (c) =>
   {
    changeCount = c.GetChangeSet().Updates.Count;
    updates = c.GetChangeSet().Updates;
    hitSubmitChanges = true;
   };
```

That (and the call to get the users) would be the only Moletypes I'd use in the test. The rest of it would be normal. Then I can use assertions to check the values of changeCount, updates and hitSubmitChanges.

Comment: Note for others: MDataContext requires as used here requires creating a Mole for System.Data.Linq.